# C# - Dynamic buttons with dynamic data-entering

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, closures, eventhandler

I have a bit of an issue here.

I'm trying to create dynamic clickevents with variable data.

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.Devices.Length; i++)
{
    Button _button = new Button();
    _button.Size = new Size(100, 15);
    _button.Text = data.Devices[i].Alias;
    _button.Name = "textbox" + i.ToString();
    _button.Location = new Point(x,y);
    x += 110;

    if(x > 1850)
    {
        y += 50;
        x = 10;
    }

    if (data.Devices[i].OnlineState == "Online")
    {
        _button.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        _button.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

     _button.Click += (Sender, args) =>
     {
         MessageBox.Show(data.Devices[i].Alias);
     };

     Controls.Add(_button);
 }
```

The idea here is that I'll create buttons until length of the list is done (The list and position of these objects vary).

What I'm looking for is to make a bunch of buttons, and when you click on the button there should you'll open another screen with some statistics attached to that object.

Since the data will vary A LOT there is no way to hardcode each scenario, but instead I'm looking to do the same thing as you can do in Android, see below.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(i);
    final int id_ = btn.getId();
    btn.setText("button " + id_);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 80, 90));
    linear.addView(btn, params);
    btn1 = ((Button) findViewById(id_));

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Kind Regards.

Comment: What's the issue you are encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start off by creating the buttons with the and placing them on the screen.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Devices.Length; i++){
Button _button = new Button();
_button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 55);
_button.Text = data.Devices[i].Alias;
_button.Name = "dynamicButton";
_button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
_button.Tag =   data.Devices[i].Alias + "|" + 
                data.Devices[i].DeviceId + "|" + 
                data.Devices[i].LastSeen + "|" + 
                data.Devices[i].OnlineState + "|" + 
                data.Devices[i].Description + "|" + 
                data.Devices[i].RemotecontrolId; 

_button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
x += 110;
if (x > 1850)
{
    y += 60;
    x = 30;
}
_button.Click += new EventHandler(bt_click);
Controls.Add(_button);
}
```

And then using the onclick event.

```
protected void bt_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        String[] information = btn.Tag.ToString().Split('|');
        String present = "Namn: " + information[0]
                        + "\nDeviceID: " + information[1]
                        + "\nSenast uppe: " + information[2]
                        + "\nStatus: " + information[3]
                        + "\nEmail: " + information[4]
                        + "\nTW-ID: " + information[5];
        MessageBox.Show(present);
        //DO THE THINGS WITH THE INFORMATION                
    }
```

And then to unload everything and eventually updating the status of the device.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            foreach (Control item in Controls.OfType<Control>())
            {
                if (item.Name == "dynamicButton")
                {
                    Controls.Remove(item);                        
                }
            }
        }
```

For some reason I have to loop that thing a couple of times, beacuse it won't delete them all, but instead deleting them in some pattern.
(only takes every other one each time)

I looped it 10 times for good measures.

It does exactly what I want it to do, and new devices gets added automaticly and removed devices dissapears just as fast.

Comment: Glad to hear it works.  Personally I would have tried to avoid the string manipulation and gone with `_button.Tag =   data.Devices[i]` and refer to that in the event handler `Device d = (Device)((Button)sender).Tag;`

Comment: I think the problem with the loop is that you're iterating over a collection that you're modifying.  `Controls.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Name == "dynamicButton");`

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you are experiencing is regarding [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

In your example you are adding the event handler with a delegate that's referencing the variable `i` which changes each loop iteration.  So when the event handler is actually executed (when the button is clicked) `i` is out of scope.

You could do something like this:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = new[] { "Item One", "Item Two", "Item Three", "Item Four", "Item Five" };

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        var btn = new Button
        {
            Text = $"Button {i + 1}",
            Tag = items[i]
        };

        btn.Click += (object obj, EventArgs args) 
            =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Hello.  {((Button)obj).Tag}");
            };

        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

In your case - the button's tag can be set to `data.Devices[i]` - in other words it doesn't have to be a string it can be an object.

Comment: Hi PeteGo, I was able to figure something out that works (sort of) what I want. The code is posted below.